# saving app data fields upon user termination or app going to background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My App need to save some data (around 100 double fields that is stored in array and some few other string data as well). I have a method  -(void) case2save  already in place to save data to the NSDocumentDirectory when the user initiates it and all is working well, however I need to save the same data when the App is terminated either by the user (home) or by the iOS.

I'm trying to use the applicationDidEnterBackground from the delegate to call that same method i use in the view controller .m class but since the function is per the object (not class method) i can't, but then if i'm making it to be class method i don't have the actual data which is part of the object... so that's the issue.

An idea how to resolve that issue and save the data when App is terminated  or goes to the background ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make that function  in appdelegate , or just declare a data member of that class in appdelegate.h and make it property and set this data member as self in that function where you are trying to save data , use following.....

```
//in Your Appdelegate.h suppose you have viewController named AbcViewController ....
AbcViewController  *abcVC;

create property ...
@property (nonatomic,retain) AbcViewController  *abcVC;

//in Your Appdelegate.m
@synthesize  abcVC;

//Now in function where you are trying to save database .....

AppdelegateClass   *app = (AppdelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 app.abcVC = self;

 //now call that function from applicationDidEnterBackground with the help of this object...
```

Hope this will resolve your issue...

Comment: the last two lines that goes in the Appdelegate.m having syntax issue as i'm getting errors. Do i need to import something extra? (i'm using 5.1)

Comment: yes you have to import appdelegate class in that view controller (AbcViewController.m) class

Comment: at which line you are getting the error can you put that here...
AppdelegateClass   *app = (AppdelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 app.abcVC = self;
if you are talking about these lines this line will go in your view contrller class where you have made that function .....

Comment: in my AbcViewController.m i tried   #import "AppDelegate.h" but it errors only if i do #import AbcAppDelegate.h it will take it but than i get the error in the Appdelegate.m using those last two lines you posted as is (or app.abcVC = self i get a warning incompatible pointer types) ..  ummm i'm missing something here..

Comment: ok, i'll try your last comment regarding the placing.. though i'm not sure how is my case2save method would be called..

Comment: suppose you have a xyz() method in your AbcViewController ... then you have to call it applicationDidEnterBackground in this method ...
[abcVC xyz];

Answer (score 0):

There is a notification sent, called `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`.  You can listen for that in your view controller and do whatever you need in response.